# get parameters from a fitted custom pyspark transformer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, transformer-model

Suppose the next Pyspark custom transformer:

```
class CustomTransformer(MockTransformer, Identifiable, PysparkReaderWriter, MLReadable, MLWritable):

    def __init__(self, output_col):
        self.output_col = output_col
        self.feat_cols = None
        super(CustomTransformer, self).__init__()

    def _transform(self, df):

        self.feat_cols = get_match_columns(df, "ops")
        # Do something smart here with this feat_cols
        df = df.drop(*self.feat_cols)

        return df
```

where `feat_cols` is calculated and setter inside the `_transform()` method, and `get_match_columns` is a function which returns the column names that match some pattern. I need to access this parameter once the pipeline containing this transformer has been transformed, for example:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[custom_transformer, assembler])
myPipe = pipeline.fit(data)
result = myPipe.transform(data)
```

with some method like:

```
result.stages[0].getParam('feat_cols')
```

but, obviously, it doesn't work. I've tried to follow this [wrapper](https://raufer.github.io/2018/02/08/custom-spark-models-with-python-wrappers/), coding this getter in my transformer:

```
def getFeatCols(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.feat_cols)
```

but I still can not recover the parameter (either     `result.stages[0]._java_obj.getParam('feat_cols')` works).

Is there any way to solve this in Pyspark?

Comment: `Paramas` are not class fields, but special types of objects - I'd strongly suggest checking how PySpark ML uses these for built-in functions. Additionally there is no reason for your last piece of code at all, as there is no backing Java object in your code.

Comment: Thank you, could you give an example? And, you are right, my backing Java object is not in this post, but it's in my wrapper.

Comment: Honestly, that's to much work for SO answer. If you can reduce to your question to a [mcve] (with stress on both _minimal_ and _complete_) I'll be happy to help. But in practice it might easier for you to take arbitrary existing wrapper and decompose it, focusing on `Param` and `Params` and `JavaML*` classes - there is single wiring under the covers, so once you grasp one model, its easy to apply the same rules to any other.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think that it was very useful. I already have a solution and, although it is true that the question may not be clear, I will answer with what has worked for me, maybe someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

As @user10938362 noted in the comment, it is necessary to use Param. In this particular case, the code that works to me is:

```
from pyspark.ml.param import Param

class CustomTransformer(MockTransformer, Identifiable, PysparkReaderWriter, MLReadable, MLWritable):

    def __init__(self, output_col):
        super(CustomTransformer, self).__init__()
        self.output_col = output_col
        self.feat_cols = Param(self, "feat_cols", "Feature columns")
        self._set(feat_cols=[]) # set or _set depends on the Spark version


    def _transform(self, df):
        self._set(feat_cols=get_match_columns(df, "ops"))
        # Do something smart here with this feat_cols
        df = df.drop(*self.getFeatCols())

        return df

    def getFeatCols(self):

        return self.getOrDefault("feat_cols")
```